# Updating a field in a table for multiple users (array) in Zend Framework V 1.8

Tags: php, variables, zend-framework, foreach

I have a user_id array:

```
$user_id = Array ();
```

And I want to create different variable names for each object:

```
//Something like $this->user_0, $this->user_1, $this->user_2, ...

$i=0;
foreach ($this->user_id as $id){
    $var = 'this->user'.$i;
    $$var = new DatabaseObject_User($db);
    $$var->loadForUser($db, $id);
    $i++;
}
```

I want Something like $this->user_0, $this->user_1, $this->user_2, different variables for each Object.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just use an array

Comment: @Travesty3 I want to create different variables: $this->user_0, $this->user_1, $this->user_2... for each Object

Comment: @82din: Got it. You might just want to comment on your code sample, so it's more obvious that it's an example of what you've tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. You will have no end of troubles attempting to iterate and test these properties.

Simply use an array, eg

```
class Whatever {
    private $user_id = []; // PHP 5.4 syntax, use array() if not applicable
    private $users = [];

    public function loadUsers() {
        foreach ($this->user_id as $id){
            $user = new DatabaseObject_User($db); // dunno where $db comes from
            $user->loadForUser($db, $id);
            $this->users[] = $user;
        }
    }
```

You can then access each user via an array index, eg

```
$this->users[n]; // where n is some integer; 0 <= n < count($this->users)
```

or iterate the array

```
foreach ($this->users as $user) {
    /* @var $user DatabaseObject_User */
}
```

Comment: I'm making some tests with your solution, Can I access users like this: $this->users[n]->user_id ? thanks!

Comment: @82din: Assuming your `DatabaseObject_User` class has a public `user_id` property, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want them to be individual variables instead of just storing an array of users, but I think you're looking for this:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($this->user_id as $id){
    $var = 'user'.$i;
    $this->$var = new DatabaseObject_User($db);
    $this->$var->loadForUser($db, $id);
    $i++;
}
```

Keep in mind that it's generally a bad idea to dynamically declare class properties. It's not obvious that those properties exist and they're automatically made public. You might want to consider just using a `$users` class property.

Comment: Thank you @Travesty3, I did an update to the question